# How to insert a blank row once value is changed in a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert a blank row once the customer Id gets changed. I have this work but on a large scale of data takes so much time. Is there a faster approach to achieve the same? Thank you.

```
Public Sub SplitRanges()

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set StWs = WB.Sheets("data")
Dim irw As Integer, iCl As Integer
Dim oRng As Range: Set oRng = StWs.Range("E2") 'where column Customer ID

irw = oRng.Row
iCl = oRng.Column

Do
    On Error Resume Next '<-------- force it to continue as getting Over flow
    If Cells(irw + 1, iCl) <> Cells(irw, iCl) Then
        Cells(irw + 1, iCl).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
        irw = irw + 2
    Else
        irw = irw + 1
    End If
Loop While Not Cells(irw, iCl).Text = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: There are several ways to do this.  Which one is best will depend on the nature of your data and how fast is fast enough. Approximately how many rows of data, how many rows to insert.  Is data sorted.  Are there any formulas in the data.

Comment: In addition to what @chrisneilsen writes, is the range all **data** or are there formulas that also need to be considered.  Is the separation only for appearance? Or are there formatting or aggregation considerations also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A faster method would be to insert all rows at once (and not one at a time) using `Union` to marge multiple rows to 1 range.

***Modified code***

```
Public Sub SplitRanges()

Dim WB As Workbook, StWs As Worksheet
Dim irw As Long, iCl As Long
Dim oRng As Range, InsertRng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set StWs = WB.Sheets("data")
Set oRng = StWs.Range("E2") 'where column Customer ID

irw = oRng.Row
iCl = oRng.Column

With StWs
    Do
        If .Cells(irw + 1, iCl).Value <> .Cells(irw, iCl).Value Then
            ' create a Range object with all range that meet this criteria
            If InsertRng Is Nothing Then
                Set InsertRng = .Cells(irw + 1, iCl)
            Else
                Set InsertRng = Application.Union(InsertRng, .Cells(irw + 1, iCl))
            End If
        End If
        
        irw = irw + 1
    Loop While Not Cells(irw, iCl).Text = ""
    
    ' verify there's at least 1 cell in range
    If Not InsertRng Is Nothing Then
        InsertRng.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Edit 1 - Loop over a 2-D array:**

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub SplitRanges()

Dim WB As Workbook, StWs As Worksheet
Dim irw As Long, iCl As Long
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim oRng As Range, InsertRng As Range
Dim DataArr As Variant


Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set StWs = WB.Sheets("data")
Set oRng = StWs.Range("E2") 'where column Customer ID

irw = oRng.Row
iCl = oRng.Column

With StWs
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, iCl).End(xlUp).Row ' get last row
    
    ' read entire worksheet to 2-D array
    DataArr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, iCl)).Value
    
    ' -- loop over array is quicker --
    For i = irw To UBound(DataArr, 1)
        If DataArr(i + 1, iCl) <> DataArr(i, iCl) Then
            ' create a Range object with all range that meet this criteria
            If InsertRng Is Nothing Then
                Set InsertRng = .Cells(irw + 1, iCl)
            Else
                Set InsertRng = Application.Union(InsertRng, .Cells(irw + 1, iCl))
            End If
    
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' verify there's at least 1 cell in range
    If Not InsertRng Is Nothing Then
        InsertRng.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: And it would be much faster still to loop over an array rather than the range

Comment: @chrisneilsen agreed, I bench-marked it once, not by much. This would still improve the code run-time by a whole lot, and would not confuse the user with array, which would make the code look entirely different.

Comment: fyi using Union to build a non-contiguous range does not scale well.  The time taken to add another non-contiguous range to the target range increases with the square of the number of non-contiguous ranges already in the target range.  I did a few tests: with a range of 4000 rows, with 400 inserts your code is 3.5x faster. With 40,000 rows and 4000 inserts you code is actually slower than the OP's code (takes more than twice as long).  So wether or not this is a good answer for the OP depends entierly on the OPs data, which so far they haven't clarified

Comment: @chrisneilsen interesting, I might need to re-test. When I tested this code about 2 years ago, with data that varies from 20K rows to 30K rows it was 10-20 times faster

Comment: @ShaiRado@chri neilsen, Thank you for your answer but still getting Over flow. this should work perfectly on a small scale of data, but the data I'm testing on is quite large. My data is approx 50K rows and the rows that will be inserted are around 7.5K rows.

Comment: @user21891380 try the edited code using a 2-D arrays

Comment: @ShaiRado Thank you so much. works much faster. I just added  If Not DataArr(i, iCl) = "Bottom" Then  as gets out of subscription at the last row where's the bottom is.